# Golf a transcendental number

Tags: code-golf, math, number

### Definitions

- An algebraic number is a number that is a zero of a non-zero polynomial with integer coefficients. For example, the square root of `2` is algebraic, because it is a zero of `x^2 - 2`.
- A transcendental number is a real number which is not algebraic.

### Task

You are to choose a transcendental number.

Then, write a program/function that takes a positive integer `n` and output the `n`-th **decimal** digit after the decimal point of your chosen transcendental number. You must state clearly in your submission, which transcendental number is used.

You can use 0-indexing or 1-indexing.

### Example

`e^2=7.389056098...` is a transcendental number. For this number:

```
n output
1 3
2 8
3 9
4 0
5 5
6 6
7 0
8 9
9 8
...
```

Note that the initial `7` is ignored.

As I mentioned above, you can choose other transcendental numbers.

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). Lowest score in bytes wins.

Comment: How do the different answers handle the fact that there is a finite number of integers that can be used as an argument? 0 would be an acceptable answer since a transcendental number exists whose first maxInteger digits are 0

Comment: @WNG Languages have arbitrary precision. There is no maxinteger.

Comment: @WNG You can think of the input index as a string, not an integer, in languages that don't have arbitrarily large number types.

Answer (score 122):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/2/), 3 bytes

```python
min
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#S7ON@Z@bmfe/oCgzr0RBXV0vKz8zTyM6TaO4pEijQlMzLb9IoUIhM0@hKDEvPVXD0MBAM1bzPwA)

Takes a number string, outputs its smallest digit as a smallest character. For example, `254` gives `2`. The decimal with these digits starts

```python
0.0123456789011111111101222222220123333333012344444401234555550123456666012345678801234567
```

This is [OEIS A054054](https://oeis.org/A054054).

**Claim:** This number `c` is transcendental

**Proof:**  Note that `c` is very sparse: almost all of its digits are zero. That's because large `n`, there's high probability `n` has a zero digit, giving a digit min of zero. Moreover, `c` has long runs of consecutive zeroes. We use an existing result that states this means `c` is transcendental.

Following this [math.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/6321/24654), let `Z(k)` represent the position of the `k`'th nonzero digit of `c`, and let `c_k` be that nonzero digit, a whole number between `1` and `9`. Then, we express the decimal expansion of `c`, but only taking the nonzero digits, as as the sum over `k=1,2,3,...` of `c_k/10^Z(k)`.

We use the result of [point 4 of this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/6565/24654) by George Lowther: that `c` is transcendental if there are infinitely many runs of zeroes that are at least a constant fraction of the number of digits so far. Formally, there must be an `ε>0` so that `Z(k+1)/Z(k) > 1+ε` for infinitely many `k`. We'll use `ε=1/9`

For any number of digits `d`, take `k` with `Z(k) = 99...99` with `d` nines.  Such a `k` exists because this digit in `c` is a `9`, and so nonzero. Counting up from `99...99`, these numbers all contain a zero digit, so it marks the start of a long run of zeroes in `c`. The next nonzero digit isn't until `Z(k+1) = 1111...11` with `d+1` ones. The ratio `Z(k+1)/Z(k)` slightly exceeds `1+1/9`.

This satisfies the condition for every `d`, implying the result.

Comment: I would be quite excited to see the proof.

Comment: Is this allowed? `min` itself doesn't take any input and doesn't provide any output, something that seems to be a requirement by the question. Sure, it's the key function in the whole, but it doesn't do anything without the generator and print statement apparent in the 'Try it online'.

Comment: @Mast Yes, the problem is to output the n'th digit given n, not to generate the decimal. The test code is to show the sequence of digits. And an expression that evaluates to a function, including a function literal, is [a valid function submission](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2441/20260).

Comment: delightful :)))

Comment: Holy sh1t, this is clever!

Answer (score 41):

## Pyth, 1 byte

```
h
```

Input and output are strings. The function takes the first digit of the index. The resulting transcendental number looks like:

`0.0123456789111111111122222222223 ...`

This is transcendental because it is `1/9` plus a number which has stretches of zeroes of length at least a constant fraction of the number. Based on [this math.stackexchange answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6321/have-all-numbers-with-sufficiently-many-zeros-been-proven-transcendental/6565#6565), that means that the number is transcendental.

There are stretches of zeroes are from digit `100 ... 000` to `199 ... 999`, so ratio of `Z(k+1)` to `Z(k)` is 2 infinitely often.

Thus, the above number minus `1/9` is transcendental, and so the above number is transcendental.

Comment: Note that the _question asked_ in the linked M.SE post does not apply to this number, but point 4 of the answer by George Lowther does.

Answer (score 16):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 19 bytes

```python
lambda n:1>>(n&~-n)
```

The **n**<sup>th</sup> digit is **1** if **n** is a power of **2** and **0** otherwise.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#S1OwVYj5n5OYm5SSqJBnZWhnp5GnVqebp/m/oCgzr0QhN7FAI01HoSgxLz1Vw1BHwchQU/M/AA)

Comment: I was going to answer this, but I found no proof of its transcendence. What makes you believe this number is transcendent? `n&~-n>0` is shorter by the way.

Comment: @orlp [All sufficiently sparse numbers are transcendental](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6321/have-all-numbers-with-sufficiently-many-zeros-been-proven-transcendental).

Comment: @orlp [Fredholm's number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_number#Numbers_proven_to_be_transcendental)

Comment: @orlp I'd have to ask the OP if Booleans are fine.

Comment: @Dennis I would prefer not.

Comment: @Dennis [What booleans?](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM69EI6SoNFXB1lbBUJMLIuCWmFMMFjGAicCUGGn@/w8A)

Comment: @Scrooble [These Booleans.](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM69Eo6SyIFUjpKg0VVNHAcx2S8wpTtXU/P8fAA "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Comment: @orlp You could submit for gcc/g++: `-Df(n)=n&~-n>0`

Answer (score 12):

## brainfuck, 2 bytes

```
,.
```

Similarly to some other answers, returns the first decimal digit and ignores the rest.

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
e!€
```

Uses Liouville's constant.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@5@q@Khpzf///w0B)

Answer (score 5):

### Retina, 4 bytes

```
1!`.
```

Returns the first digit of the input number. Because that port was so boring, here are some more ports:

```
O`.
1!`.
```

(8 bytes) Returns the minimum digit of the input number.

```
.+
$*
+`^(11)+$
$#1$*
^1$
```

(25 bytes) Returns 1 if the input number is a power of 2.

```
.+
$*_

$.`
+1`.(\d*)_
$1
1!`.
```

(30 bytes) Champernowne's constant.

Answer (score 4):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog) 2, 7 bytes

```
⟦₁c;?∋₎
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brachylog2#@/9o/rJHTY3J1vaPOrofNfX9/29k8D8KAA)

Calculates digits of the Champernowne constant (possibly times a power of ten due to indexing issues, which clearly don't matter here). Basically, this just concatenates together integers, and then takes the *nth* digit.

Comment: Why do you need `⟦₁`?

Comment: @LeakyNun: Because otherwise we'd start concatenating numbers with 0, and you can't do that because `0123` is not a number (it has a leading zero, which doesn't fit within Brachylog's concept of what a number is).

Answer (score 4):

## Python 2, 13 bytes

Input and output are strings.

```
lambda n:n[0]
```

The number's nth digit is the most significant digit of n when it is written in decimal.

Comment: You should include why this number is transcendental.

Comment: @orlp Looks like xnor's reference can easily be applied here too -- subtract 1/9 from the number and then Z(n+1) / Z(n) ~= 2 infinitely often (between 10^x and 2 * 10^x).

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 7 bytes

```
4YA50<A
```

This uses the first of the two numbers given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moser%E2%80%93de_Bruijn_sequence#Decimal_reciprocals) divided by 3 (which [maintains transcendence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_number#Properties)):

> 1.100110000000000110011...

Input is 1-based.
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@28S6WhqYOP4/78hAA) Or [see the first 20 decimals](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#s1Jy@G8S6WhqYOP4P1Yt47@RAQA).

#### Explanation

```
4YA     % Convert to base 4 using chars '0', '1', '2', '3' as digits
50<A    % Are all digits less than '2'? Gives 0 (false) or 1 (true)
```

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, 43 bytes

Champernowne's constant.

```
lambda n:"".join(`i`for i in range(n+1))[n]
```

Comment: Why do you need `n+1`?

Comment: @LeakyNun Because else I get indexing errors for n <= 1.

Comment: You can use 1-indexing.

Comment: @LeakyNun n <= 1.

Comment: I think you need to specify Python 2 for this one.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript, 51 bytes

This function computes `n`th digit of Champernowne's Constant. Add `f=` at the beginning and invoke like `f(arg)`. Note that `n` is 1-indexed.

```
n=>[..."1".repeat(n)].map((c,i)=>c*++i).join``[n-1]
```

### Explanation

This function takes in a single argument `n`. It, then, creates an `n`-characters long String of repetitive 1s. Then, it splits that String into an Array of 1s . After that, it iterates over every element of the Array and multiplies them with their index in the Array incremented by 1. Then, it joins the Array together over `""` (empty String) to form a String. At last, it returns the `n`th element of the obtained String.

**Note:** *The type of the returned value is always String*.

### Test Snippet

```js
let f =

n=>[..."1".repeat(n)].map((c,i)=>c*++i).join``[n-1]

i.oninput = e => o.innerHTML = f(parseInt(e.target.value,10));
```

```html
<input id=i><pre id=o></pre>
```

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 3 bytes

```apl
2|⍴
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/apl-dyalog#@@/4qG2CUc2j3i3//zs@6pjxqHfqoRWPejcbGgABAA) (the test suite generates a range of numbers from `1` to `10000`, converts them to a string, and then applies the train `2|⍴` on them).

Takes the input number as a string and returns its length mod 2. So `123` => `3 mod 2` => `1`.

The sequence starts off like so:

```apl
1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  ...
```

so this can be generalised like so: `9 1s 90 0s 900 1s ...`

Multiplying this number by 9 gives us a [Liouville number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number), which is proven to be transcendental.

Comment: I don't think this is necessarily a Liouville number - it's not obvious to me that you can get n>10. It *does* fit the stronger theorem other people here have been using, though.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen You can express it as `1 - 10^-9 + 10^-99 - 10^-999 + 10^-9999 - 10^-99999 + ...`, so it is a Liouville number.

Comment: @LeakyNun The fraction of consecutive exponents is approximately 10, but to fit the definition on Wikipedia it needs to be unbounded - that's why the original Liouville's constant's 1-indices use a factorial, and not an exponential.

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, <s>25 bytes</s> 17 bytes

```
(!!)$concat$map show[1..]
```

[Champernowne's Constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Champernowne_constant) can be 0 or 1 indexed as C10*.01 is still transcendental.

Edit:
as per nimis comment you can use the list monad to reduce this to

```
(!!)$show=<<[1..]
```

Comment: `=<<` from the list monad is `concat.map`: `(!!)$show=<<[1..]`.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, 73 bytes

This is a program which computes the `n`th digit of the Liouville Constant, where `n` is the input number given by invoking the function `g` as `g(arg)` (and `n` is 1-indexed). Note that the newline in the code is necessary.

```
f=n=>n<1?1:n*f(n-1);g=(n,r=0)=>{for(i=0;i<=n;i++)if(f(i)==n)r=1
return r}
```

### Explanation

The program consists of two functions, `f` and `g`. `f` is a recursive factorial-computing function, and `g` is the main function of the program. `g` *assumes* to have a single argument `n`. It defines a default argument `r` with a value of 0. It, then, iterates over all the Integers from 0 to `n`, and, in each iteration, checks whether the function `f` applied over `i` (the current index) equals `n`, i.e. whether `n` is a factorial of `i`. If that happens to be the case, `r`'s value is set to 1. At the end of the function, `r` is returned.

### Snippet for Testing

```js
f=n=>n<1?1:n*f(n-1);g=(n,r=0)=>{for(i=0;i<=n;i++)if(f(i)==n)r=1
return r}

i.oninput = e => o.innerHTML = g(parseInt(e.target.value,10))
```

```html
<input id=i><pre id=o></pre>
```

**Warning:** *Don't put a very large value in the Snippet's input box! Otherwise, your device may freeze!*

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 1 byte

```
Ḣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/9wx6L///@rGxoYqAMA)

1st digit of quoted 0-indexed input.<sup>1</sup>

<sup><sup>1</sup>See isaacg's answer for proof of validity.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>3</s> <s>1+1= 2</s> 1 byte

Another port of [feersum's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/120631/58974).

Takes input as a string.

```
g
```

[Try it online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.4&code=Zw==&input=IjgwIg==)

---

### Explanation

```
   :Implicit input of string U
g  :The first character of the string
```

Comment: The input can be a string, so you can do `g` for 1 byte :)

Comment: The challenge doesn't make mention of string input, @obarakon, so I used integers in my [JS ports](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/120676/58974) and then, in turn, here.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. A lot of the other answers used string inputs. But you're right, the OP didn't mention it in the challenge.

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, <s>7</s> <s>5</s> 4 bytes

```
@jkS
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%40jkUh&input=10&debug=0)

Uses Champernowne's constant.

Saved <s>2</s> 3 bytes thanks to Leaky Nun.

Comment: you can use `jk` to replace `sm\`d`, I believe.

Comment: Can you use `S` instead of `Uh`?

Comment: I think they are functionally identical, so yes. I totally read through the docs >.>

Comment: They aren't functional identical. `S` starts with `1` and `U` starts with `0`.

Comment: Why did you revert your edit? The resulting number is still transcendental.

Comment: Yeah, turns out I have to do that for my answer to be valid actually lol

Comment: @LeakyNun it's not the Champernowne constant though

Comment: But it's still transcendental, right? It is essentially a shifted Champernowne constant.

Comment: Yeah, it's transcendental, but using `S` is shorter anyway

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 18 bytes

Same as [Dennis' answer for Python 2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/120630/58251), the [Fredholm number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_number#Numbers_proven_to_be_transcendental)

```
n->(n&(n-1))>0?0:1
```

Comment: `(n-1)` can be `~-n` or `--n` to save 2 bytes. Or you can have the exact same as _Dennis_' answer: `n->1>>(n&~-n)` or `1>>(n&--n)`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 24 bytes (noncompeting)

```
ＮαＡＩＵＶN⟦ＵＧPi⁺α¹⟧β§β⁺α›α⁰
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/charcoal#@/9@z7pzG9/vWfh@z8r3e7a@37PN79H8ZWDW8oDMR427zm08tPPR/OXnNh0CYjD/UQOIaNzw/78JAA)

**Note:** As of post time, does not work for `n` where  `n` is a positive multiple of 14.

## Explanation

```
Ｎα                             Input number to a
   Ａ                  β        Assign to b
     Ｉ                         Cast
       ＵＶN                    Evaluate variable N
            ⟦ＵＧPi⁺α¹⟧         With arguments GetVariable(Pi) and a+1
                        §β⁺α›α⁰ Print b[a+(a>0)]
```

Comment: `GetVariable(Pi)`? So, there's no `π` predefined variable?

Comment: @Neil Not yet, and I'm not intending to make `π` equal to pi because this is an ASCII-art oriented language, not a math-oriented one

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>3</s> 1 byte

**EDIT**: Using the proof from the other answers, returns the first digit of input

```
¬
```

1-indexed for π (only up to 100000 digits)

```
žs¤
```

How it works

```
žs  # Implicit input. Gets n digits of pi (including 3 before decimal)
  ¤ # Get last digit
```

Or, if you prefer e (still 1-indexed) (only up to 10000 digits)

```
žt¤
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@390X/GhJf//GxoYGAAA)

Answer (score 1):

## TI-BASIC, 16 bytes

Basically tests if the input `N` (1-indexed) is a triangular number.  This is the same as returning the `N`th digit of 0.1010010001…, which is [proven](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/781687/101777) to be transcendental.  The sequence of digits is [OEIS A010054](https://oeis.org/A010054).

```
Input N
int(√(2N
2N=Ans(Ans+1
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Duocentehexaquinquagesimal](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Duocentehexaquinquagesimal), 1 byte

*Ties [isaacg's Pyth answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/120639/94066), [Erik the Outgolfer's Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/120683/94066), [Neil A.'s 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/120983/94066), and [Shaggy's Japt answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/121403/94066) for #1.*

```
.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifnFhiYxPzqGGRXbx1cWqKgm6mgrphsXWcNVDIWl0hXsHILq80x7qkqDQPqDRVQbdY11Ah3jo1OSNfQTdPQR2oLOnQMuPDW5yP7stQsrPR1tXTiY5VetSw0Evdzg6isEY/v6BEP784MSkzFUopxNslWYOFk4oSM/PSSpOzESyFpP96/4EG/zc0MgYA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 5 bytes

```
Đř!∈Ɩ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//yISjMxUfdXQcm/b/v5EJAA)

Liouville Constant

```
Đ           implicit input (n); duplicate
 ř!         get [1!,2!,...,n!]
   ∈        is n in that list?
    Ɩ       coerce to integer; implicit print
```

Answer (score 1):

## Regex (ECMAScript), 13 bytes

```
((xx|)x*)\1+$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY/NTsJAFEZfpTaG3kttocQYwziwcsGGhS6RxQQu7dXpdDIzQOVn6wP4iL5IxQWJybc7i@@cd7VTfuXYhsxbXpOrG/NBn52ThvbRC5XPrQU4yMmg30E7vQzbPr4V6W3XHxwwD81rcGxKwNxrXhE83GX3iMLLodhXrAlAS0dqrdkQIN5Is9Uaj6XUubeaAyRZgoI3AEaWuSZThgono9OJ/VzNgaVVztPMBCgXwyXiFdB/YCbFtBj/YQyVa/bxzOyU5nXklClpHMWpFpvGgeAnSYLTFC@HtYzbOHdkSQVgzGsVVhU4xKPv9ewlKsBfRyHsNvjggNMk@vn6jpK0XoyWV1VxPndFVowefwE)

Takes its input in unary, as a string of `x` characters whose length represents the number. The output is returned as the length of capture group `\2`.

Returns the \$n\$th digit of \$0.00020202220202220202220222220202222202220202220222220...\$, where the \$n\$th digit is \$2\$ if \$n\$ is a composite number, and \$0\$ otherwise.

```
           # tail = N = input number
((xx|)x*)  # \1 = the largest proper divisor of N;
           # \2 = 2 if \1 >= 2, or 0 otherwise;
           # tail -= \1
\1+$       # Assert that \1 divides tail
```

If the return value of `\2` is defined to be \$0\$ when it is unset, then this can be reduced to **12 bytes**, with \$0.00010101110101110101110111110101111101110101110111110...\$ as the transcendental number:

```
(x?(x)*)\1+$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY/NTsJAFEZfpTaG3kttocQYQx1YuWDDQpfoYgKX6dXpdDIzQOVn6wP4iL5IhUQTN9/mLL5z3uRW@qVjGzJveUWubsw7fXROGNpFT6QeWwuwF5NBv4N2Ci328aVIr7v@YI95aJ6DY6MAc695SXB3k90ill4My13FmgC0cCRXmg0B4pUwG63xoITOvdUcIMkSLHkNYITKNRkVKpyMjkf2czkHFlY6TzMTQC2Gr4h/gP4DMymmxfiCMVSu2cUzs5WaV5GTRtE4ilNdrhsHJT8IKjlN8XxYi7iNc0eWZADGvJZhWYFDPPhez56jAlw6itJugg8OOE2i78@vKEmhXoxep5f5FR4Pz8mnU1dkxej@Bw)

#### Regex (ECMAScript), 14 bytes

```
((x*)(?=\2)x)*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc@9bsIwFIbhW0kzkHOSJpCoqipcw9SBhaEdKYMFB8et41i2gZSftRfQS@yNpDAgdX6G73s/xE74lVM25N6qNbmmNZ/01TtuaB@9knzpLMCBT4ZpD9ClCFP@XmGHaZ8OD1iE9i04ZSRg4bVaETze5w@IzPMR29dKE4DmjsRaK0OAeMfNVms8Sq4Lb7UKkOQJMrUBMFwWmowMNU6q00n5uZiD4lY4TzMTQC5GS8Qb0H8wk3Jajq@MoXbtPp6ZndBqHTlhJI2jONNs0zpg6pkTU1mGl8GGx11cOLIkAigsGhFWNTjEox8M7CUqwLWjZHYbfHCgsiT6/f6JkqxZVMvbVXY@92VeVk9/)

The output of this one is also returned as the length of capture group `\2`.

Returns the \$n\$th digit of \$0.01001100001111000000001111111100000000000000001...\$ (with 1-indexing). The \$n\$th digit of this transcendental number is the 2nd digit of the binary expansion of \$n+1\$, [OEIS A079944](https://oeis.org/A079944).

```
                # tail = N = input number
(
    (x*)(?=\2)  # \2 = floor(tail / 2); tail -= \2
    x           # tail -= 1
)*              # Iterate the above as many times as possible
```

Answer (score 0):

## Fourier, 16 bytes

```
I~NL~S10PS~XN/Xo
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/nexus/fourier#@@9Z5@dTF2xoEBBcF@GnH5H//7@xuQUA)

As other answers have done, outputs the first digit of the input.

An explanation of the code:

```
N = User Input
S = log(N)
X = 10 ^ S
Print (N/X)
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6)

Just a few ports of some other solutions

---

### [feersum's Python solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/120631/58974), 12 bytes

```
n=>(""+n)[0]
```

```js
f=
n=>(""+n)[0]
o.innerText=f(i.value=1)
i.oninput=_=>o.innerText=f(+i.value)
```

```html
<input id=i type=number><pre id=o>
```

---

### [Dennis' Python solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/120630/58974), 13 bytes

```
n=>1>>(n&--n)
```

```js
f=
n=>1>>(n&--n)
o.innerText=f(i.value=1)
i.oninput=_=>o.innerText=f(+i.value)
```

```html
<input id=i type=number><pre id=o>
```

---

### [xnor's Python solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/120635/58974), 20 bytes

```
n=>Math.min(...""+n)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 6 + 3 ( `-c`) = 9 bytes

```
({}<>)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brain-flak#@69RXWtjp/n/v6GBwX/dZAA)

1st digit of 0-index string input (hence the `-c` flag).

Answer (score 0):

## C#, 13 bytes

```
n=>(n+"")[0];
```

From feersum's solution. Almost same solution than the js port.

[Try it online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zwjTyy)

Answer (score 0):

## J, 2 Bytes

The same solution everyone else is using:

```
{.
```

Returns the first digit of n. IO is on strings

### Liouville's Constant, 9 Bytes

```
(=<.)!inv
```

Returns `1` if input is the factorial of an integer.

### Pi, 13 Bytes

```
{:":<.@o.10x^
```

The last non-decimal digit of pi times 10^n.

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 bytes

```
LḂ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/n4Y6m////KxkbmhiaWhqZmRorAQA)

Take the length of the input number modulo 2. Equivalent to [this APL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/120674/61384).

Answer (score 0):

## [Dreaderef](https://github.com/ScratchMan544/Dreaderef), 5 bytes

```
7 3 6
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SylKTUxJLUpN@//fXMFYwez/fxMA)

Returns the first digit of the input.

Answer (score 0):

## [Momema](https://github.com/ScratchMan544/momema), 5 bytes

```
-9*-9
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y83PTc1N/P9f11JL1/L/f0MTU0MjAA)

Returns the first digit of the input.

Answer (score 0):

## [Shakespeare Programming Language](https://github.com/TryItOnline/spl), 76 bytes

```
,.Ajax,.Ford,.Act I:.Scene I:.[Enter Ajax and Ford]Ford:Open mind.Speak thy.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky7I@f9fR88xK7FCR88tvygFyE4uUfC00gtOTs1LBTGiXfNKUosUQEoUEvNSFECqYkGElX9Bap5CbmZeil5wQWpitkJJRqXe//@GxsbmAA)

Comment: You've got an extra character there

Comment: Whoops, that must have been a leftover from something else. Thanks for spotting it.

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `M`, 0 bytes

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSZmb290ZXI9JmlucHV0PTEyMyZmbGFncz1N)
or [see the start of the number](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPUwlQzQlQjEmY29kZT0mZm9vdGVyPU0lM0IlNjAwLiVDNiVBNCZpbnB1dD0xMDAmZmxhZ3M9Sg==)

Port of xnor's Python answer. The `M` flag takes the minimum of the top of stack.